# Is it allowed to create a lite version of an app for iOS?

Tags: ios, app-store, publish

There are a lot of questions and answers regarding **Lite-Version** on the *App Store*. But I am still not sure what are the **exact regulations**.

My App:

- I have a free and a full app. The difference is only the amount of content. Every button, every functionality is the same in both apps. My additional content has *question marks* **(?)** on it. When clicking on it, it shows a text mentioning, that there is a purchasable full version on the *App Store*.
- I don't like to use the *in-app purchase* feature.

Background:

- I uploaded my ***appname free*** to the *App Store* and it was accepted.
- Then one week later I made only a change in the destription in the *App Store* and for that I had (stupidly) create a new build for it. I didn't change anything in the code. This version (same code) was rejected with the reason, that the app seems to be a trial version and it is restricted in the functionality. Also it would not be allowed to show a popup pointing to the full version. I tried to explain with no success, that its not a functional restriction, but a content restriction.

This shows me, that it depends on the approvers sentiment and interpretation of Apple's publishing rules, if an app is rejected or accepted.

So is it allowed to have a free, lite version of an app? What should I do in this situation?

Comment: its definitely allowed,  lite version gives you more analytics and stuff but it is still advised to go through single app and using in app purchases. Most apps uses that format and the users expect that too. For your specific case, if the difference between lite and full version includes size too like full version is 100 mb vs 30 mb lite version; that should work in your favour. simply making 2 apps with just number of question diff is a overkill